# Can the covariance of X and Y be larger than the variance of X?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance, covariance, python

I am trying to visualize a 2D Gaussian for personal purposes. i.e this formula for the 2D case:

$$f(\mathbf x\mid \Theta_i)=|2\pi \Sigma_i|^{-\frac12}e^{-\frac12(\mathbf x-\mu_i)^T\Sigma_i^{-1}(\mathbf x-\mu_i)}$$

I coded it in python and if I input the covariance matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.9\\
0.9 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

I get the following:

[image]

Which makes perfect sense, as I expected to see some form of ellipse like shapes.

However if I input the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1.1\\
1.1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

I get this:

[image]

Which looks a bit like a saddle point.

In general, when I set the covariance matrix to be such that $\operatorname{cov}(x,y) > \operatorname{cov}(x,x) = \operatorname{cov}(y,y)$ I get the second case, which in my head isn't a valid Gaussian. Thus I suspect I have broken some property, but I can't understand why it isn't possible for the covariance of $(x,y)$ to be larger than than the covariance of $(x,x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the famous Cauchy-Scwhartz Inequality, which is used to prove that correlations are bounded by 1. This implies that $$ Cov(X,Y) \leq \sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)} $$

Comment: You are missing the absolute value notation on your answer

Answer (score 2):

For two r.v. $X$ and $Y$, a theorem in probability says $$|\text{cov}(X,Y)|\le \sigma_X\sigma_Y$$or equivalently $$|E\{\bar X\bar Y\}|^2\le E\{\bar X^2\}E\{\bar Y^2\}$$with $\bar X=X-E\{X\}$ and $\bar Y=Y-E\{Y\}$. This is an interpretation of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in probability. Based on this, a correlation coefficient $\rho$ is defined as $$\rho={\text{cov}(X,Y)\over \sigma_X\sigma_Y}$$with $$|\rho|\le 1$$so, we can say that **you have broken the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, or equivalently, the positive definiteness of the covariance matrix.**